# Using IdentityServer4 Refresh Tokens

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am looking for a simple, clear explanation of how the refresh token is used. I understand that once the access token expires, a refresh token is used to get a new access token.
Lets say a user is authenticated and gets a refresh token and an access token.

Question 1: 
When the access token expires, does IdentityServer4 (not the api that the user is trying to access) consider the user to be then "unauthenticated"?

Question 2: 
Lets say the access token expires, can i wait as long as i want before using the refresh token? I mean, if the access token expires now, and i do NOT have an immediate need to access a protected API, and that need comes up 5 hours later, can i just pick-up the refresh token and use it to get a new access token?

Question 3: 
What if i want an access token that never expires? Lets say i have an app like facebook, where users generally never really logout. How do i implement that functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that access tokens are used for clients to access resources (api) on behalf of the user. For a website that uses cookie authentication and has no external resources, there is no need for a refresh token.

*Question 1:* Assuming you are using JWT tokens: from the perspective of the resource, the request is unauthorized. As this is a direct request from client to resource, IdentityServer is not part of it.

From the websites perspective the user may still be logged in, because the cookie isn't expired. That can result in the 'odd' situation that an (for the website) authenticated user has no access to an external resource (access token expired). It's for this situation that you'll need the refresh token.

For cookie authentication there are ways to extend the lifetime of the cookie.

*Question 2:* You can wait as long as you like, but take into account that also the refresh token can expire. There are options to extend the lifetime.

Also note that you can request as many access tokens as you like. You don't have to wait until the access token expires. But this is probably not as efficient as checking the expiration of the access token.

When you configure one time use, you can use the refresh token only once. In the result of the request a new refresh token will be provided.

*Question 3:* Are you talking about a cookie or a token? For the website you can extend the lifetime of the cookie.

Comment: Thank you for your response Ruard. I think you explain very clearly. For Question 3, the issue is that i am building a Xamarin Forms application. So we are not in the context of a web application. If you consider the facebook mobile app, you can login once, when you install the application. Then you never have to authenticate again, just navigate the app as desired. The app undoubtedly access API's when you access it on any given day. So its as if you authenticate once and the app (the client) can access the API's forever, as long as you have actively logged out.

Comment: When you are in the context of mobile app you can technically issue a token which never expires but that defeats the purpose of OAuth and short lived access tokens because you cannot revoke access tokens but you can revoke refresh tokens. And thats why you should fallback to question 2. @arlvin

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius bare in my that access tokens a valuable entities so in the context of a mobile app you should make efforts to keep it as secure as possible - i.e. protect it via secure platform features like secure enclave or the android equivalent. Typically you'd ONLY want to let them exist on the client side of they are protected in that manner.